# How to programmatically create a formatted text in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I need to create a text (2 lines, multiple fonts) programmatically, that I later place in several tables (<100) of my document.

The only way I found out to solve this, is to create a `Word.Paragraph` and copy its Range to the cells. The problem with this approach is: while creating a Paragraph, it's added to the Document.

I want to create a formatted text like creating a string, all in the code without modifying the Document.

Comment: Why don't you just delete it when you're done copying it?  Or just create it in the first place you're copying it to?

Comment: The created text is not meant to be placed at the documents body. The text needs to be placed in a certain table cell on several tables wrapped in several textboxes throughout the document. I just thought that it would be possible to handle formatted text as strings.

Comment: What are you using to do this? Winforms? Can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I have used is to use HTML or richtext, which is essentially a string anyway. I am fairly sure Word can interpret either of these with the right com object settings.

Another approach I have tried is using the clipboard instead of a word object. You can do something like this:

(importing `system.windows.forms`)

```
Clipboard.SetText(Me.RichTextBox1.Rtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf)
ApplicationName.Selection.Paste()
```

Comment: With "formatted Text" I didn't meant Rtf or Html Format. It's a text with arbitrary formats with both bolded and normal characters. BTW: Altough VB6 has the Clipboard object, VBA doesn't. You have to define a DataObject's text and put that object to the clipboard. Nice approach anyway

Comment: If it was not RTF or HTML, which format was it? You cannot have text without an associated format. Plain text has no formatting, but it is called "plain text" (format) and then you cannot do bold. I think that is the default in your case unless you _tell it_ to interpret your string as something else.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use [this on hidden text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690375/programmatically-inserting-hidden-text-into-a-word-2010-table) and [this on deleting paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829947/ms-word-macro-delete-paragraphs)?

Something like this:

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()
  Dim para As Word.Paragraph

  Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Add
  para.Range.Font.Hidden = True
  ' Do your manipulation
  para.Range.Text = "Hello world"
  para.Range.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
  para.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
  ' Now remove the paragraph as if it never existed!
  para.Range.Delete


End Sub
```