# programmatically inserting hidden text into a Word 2010 table

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have a Word 2010 table with existing, visible text in it. I want to use some VBA code to insert some text into each cell and then hide the new text. I know how to insert text into a cell using VBA, I just can't figure out how to leave the existing text in the cell visible and only hide the new text.

I tried this, but it doesn't quite work:

```
For Each aTable In ActiveDocument.Tables

Rows = aTable.Rows.Count 
Cols = aTable.Columns.Count 
Dim rng As Range 
For r = 1 To Rows 
For c = 1 To Cols 
cellvalue = "Cell_ID[" & r & ", " & c & "]" 
ActiveDocument.Tables(ndx).Cell(r, c).Range.InsertAfter cellvalue 
' hides all text in the cell
'ActiveDocument.Tables(ndx).Cell(r, c).Range.Font.Hidden = True  
Selection.Font.Hidden = True 
Next 
Next 
Exit For 

Next aTable
```

Comment: Did you try to record a macro and then see what's going on?

Comment: yes, but it wasn't helpful

Comment: Change the font of that text to `white` or tables back color?

Comment: `Selection.Font.Hidden` = True works for me

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't quite work.
For Each aTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    Rows = aTable.Rows.Count
    Cols = aTable.Columns.Count
    
    Dim rng As Range

    For r = 1 To Rows
        For c = 1 To Cols
            
            cellvalue = "Cell_ID[" & r & ", " & c & "]"
            
            ActiveDocument.Tables(ndx).Cell(r, c).Range.InsertAfter cellvalue
            'ActiveDocument.Tables(ndx).Cell(r, c).Range.Font.Hidden = True ' hides all text in the cell
            Selection.Font.Hidden = True
            
        Next
    Next
    Exit For
Next aTable

Comment: Please update your question with your code - code in comments isn't very readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim rng As Range, aTable, nRows, nCols, r, c, cellvalue
Dim l

    For Each aTable In ActiveDocument.Tables

    nRows = aTable.Rows.Count
    nCols = aTable.Columns.Count

        For r = 1 To nRows
            For c = 1 To nCols
                cellvalue = "Cell_ID[" & r & ", " & c & "]"
                With aTable.Cell(r, c)
                    l = Len(.Range.Text)
                    .Range.InsertAfter cellvalue
                    Set rng = .Range
                    rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, l - 2
                    rng.Font.Hidden = True
                End With
            Next c
        Next

    Next aTable

End Sub
```